# Webrtc video chat doesn't works in my IP?

Tags: node.js, webrtc

WebRTC video chatting application  runs perfectly fine in local host. but when I try to run the same code in a specific IP im not able to perform the same task,
Error : getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins
Any ideas on how can I fix this issue?

Comment: are you running in `https` mode?

Comment: https://webrtchacks.com/chrome-secure-origin-https/ more info

Comment: No i'm  using http mode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the recent chrome release `getUserMedia()` is deprecated on insecure origins to improve browser security.

[Deprecating Powerful Features on Insecure Origins](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins).

You can disable this by opening the chrome with following flags.

> You can run chrome with the --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="example.com" flag (replacing "example.com" with the origin you actually want to test), which will treat that origin as secure for this session. Note that you also need to include the --user-data-dir=/test/only/profile/dir to create a fresh testing profile for the flag to work.

To open chrome with above flags refer [this](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags).

If you want to make this work in production without any of this workarounds, you should buy a ssl certificate and setup HTTPS connection on your server.